# Excel Duplicates based on Dates Difference

Tags: excel

I have the following issue:

Say, Column A are the different Dates in a time span of 3 years
and Column B is the "Code Number of Equipment" which is repeated from time to time.

I want to set up a rule where, excel will highlight in "Code Number of Equipment" the duplicates ONLY when the dates difference referring to the same "Code Number of Equipment" is less or equal to than 7 days.

Thanking in advance,

Comment: Are they duplicated more than once (ie. a certain code equipment has three rows belonging to it)?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to accomplish this is by use of a helper column.

The first step is to sort your data by `Code Number of Equipment` and then `Date`.

Assuming the data is sorted, you can create a helper column (such as `Time Until Next`) by using:

```
=IF(B2=B3,A3-A2,0)
```

This outputs the number of days until the next row, if the `Code Number of Equipment` matches (otherwise 0).

Now for your date column, for the first cell use conditional formatting of:

```
=C2>=7
```

This will determine whether the calculated duration (`Time Until Next`) is greater or equal to seven days as specified.

Now use the paintbrush to copy this conditional formatting down to the entire column (optionally hide `Time Until Next` if you'd like).

[image]